# How to remove EZ Sand that is sticking to pavers?

Tags: cleaning, pavers, backyard

We hired an inexperienced guy to do the pavers and he poured EZ Sand in pavers joints but didn’t do a good job of cleaning the residue that is on pavers surface.

How to fix this? Google says, do a pressure wash with hot water but looking for other options before I screw it up further.

**EDIT**: Sand is not wet and it dried. I tried scrubbing my feet on it and it is not coming off.

[image]

Comment: Is the sand still wet?  Waiting a few days for it to dry might help?

Comment: @JPhi1618 No, It dried. I tried to scrub with my feet but it is not coming off..I may have to use a metal or something to scrape it but it may damage the paver as well.

Comment: I would try the abrasives sander first, then water wash.

Comment: I bet pressure washer would work (not heated), but you want to avoid spraying directly in the cracks.  Not posting as an answer because I’ve never done it.

Comment: I would try boiling water or a blowtorch and a wire brush on the worst parts, but this problem will (eventually) take care of itself. I've also used a 2x4 as a chisel w/ a hammer to remove chunks w/o damaging bricks.